# Separating positive and negative numbers into two arrays

Tags: list-manipulation

$c$ is a vector with real numbers.I want to separate the positive ones and the negative ones into two vectors: $a$ and $b$.

I have the following problem:
When I do:

```
c = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20];
{a, b} = GatherBy[c, Positive]
```

Sometimes, $a$ is the one with positive numbers, and some other times $b$ is the one with the positive numbers. Any solution to this problematic randomness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The origin of your problem is that `GatherBy` gathers your data differently depending on the sign of the first number in list $c$.

You can avoid the problem by sorting the vector of real numbers $c$ before applying `GatherBy`, so that the $a$ list will always contain negative numbers:

```
c = Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20]];
{a, b} = GatherBy[c, Positive]
```

Comment: Try it with `c = Sort[{-2, -2}];`

Comment: @belisarius Yep, in this form it works only under the assumption that the list c contains both positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Few more alternatives:

```
c = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]
(* {-0.672076, -0.572152, -0.298228, -0.386248, 0.604312, -0.185637,
   0.983919, -0.926872, 0.479745, 0.407436} *)
{a, b} = Pick[c, Sign@c, #] & /@ {-1, 1} (* or *)
{a, b} = Cases[c, #] & /@ {_?NonPositive, _?Positive} (* or *)
{a, b} = DeleteCases[c, #] & /@ {_?Positive, _?NonPositive} (* or *)
{a, b} = Reap[If[# < 0, Sow[#, neg], Sow[#, pos]] & /@ c, {neg, pos}][[2]]
(* {{-0.672076, -0.572152, -0.298228, -0.386248, -0.185637, -0.926872},
    {0.604312, 0.983919, 0.479745, 0.407436}}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way that removes the need to sort. Either

```
 {a, b} = {Select[c, # > 0 &], Select[c, # <= 0 &]}
```

or

```
 {a, b} = {Select[c, Positive], Select[c, Negative]}
```

which do the same thing except for any zero values.

Answer (score 3):

```
c = {5, 2, -5, 3, -3, -4};
```

Using `Sort` and `SequenceSplit`:

```
SequenceSplit[Sort@c, s : {_?Negative, ___?Negative} :> s]

(*{{-5, -4, -3}, {2, 3, 5}}*)
```

Or in a shorter form as @eldo suggests:

```
SequenceSplit[Sort@c, s : {__?Negative} :> s]

(*{{-5, -4, -3}, {2, 3, 5}}*)
```

Comment: Very nice , +1. It could be shortened to `SequenceSplit[Sort@c, s : {__?Negative} :> s]`

Comment: Thanks, @eldo! That shorter form looks even better :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
c = {5, 2, -5, 3, -3, -4};
```

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup` (both came in 2014 with V 10.0)

```
{a, b} = Lookup[{-1, 1}] @ GroupBy[Sign] @ c
```

{{-5, -3, -4}, {5, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `UnitStep` and `Pick`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
c = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]
```

> {0.634779, -0.777161, 0.579052, -0.624394, -0.517278, -0.868522, 
> 0.0844932, -0.537691, -0.207988, 0.400948}

```
Pick[c, UnitStep[c], #] & /@ {0, 1}
```

---

**Using `Sow` and `Reap`:**

```
First /@ Last@Reap[Scan[
    If[# <= 0
      , Sow[#, "Negative"]
      , Sow[#, "Positive"]] &, c]
   , {"Negative", "Positive"}
   ]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{-0.777161, -0.624394, -0.517278, -0.868522, -0.537691, -0.207988}, 
> {0.634779, 0.579052, 0.0844932, 0.400948}}

Comment: (+1) Very nice, @Syed!